Installation of 3 x 3kw heaters
I have 3 x 3kw heaters to install, can I find a 32a ring with a 50a breaker or 3 single 32a supply’s be best

Can you clarify what you mean about finding a 32A ring with a 50A breaker?  Have you ever seen that, where, and how did/do you justify it?  I wonder if you just mean something different.

Given that the locations (you haven't specified) with 32A rings are 220-230V supply, a 3KW heater only needs 13.04-13.6A, so three 16A circuits would do for three 3KW heaters.
Whether you need to bump to 32A circuits for continuous load derating (commonly 125% for heating loads, which exceeds 16A unless the supply is 235V or more) will depend on your local electrical rules, that will depend on your location in the world. My recollection is that places that use 6A, 16A & 32A breakers don't commonly have 20A breakers (which would be big enough if such a derate was called for), but I don't live in one of those places.
Putting a 50A breaker on a 32A ring would be dangerous in any country, as the wiring size would be based on the expected 32A breaker.

If you have the access and budget and space in the CU to install a dedicated breaker and cabling for each heater, that would be ideal so that you don't have these heaters each predictably occupying 40% of the capacity on a ring with other things.  If you do take this approach, a 16A spur for each one is adequate, you don't need rings.
You could put one or two of them on an existing 32A ring, so long as there isn't much else on it. But no 50A breakers ... if you can explain that idea more in the question it would help, but for now I'll just dismiss it.
You could put all three of them on a 32A ring so long as you don't use all three of them at once.  If you do the breaker should pop as designed.  It's not unusual for a ring to have more things installed than can all be used at once.   But if it's known that these heaters will routinely all be used together, you obviously should not proceed this way.

For three 3kw heaters, three separate 32A supplies could be the best option to evenly distribute the load and prevent overloading. Consulting with a qualified electrician is advisable for tailored guidance to ensure safety and efficiency.

Downvoted because the advice seems generic and possibly AI-generated.    Distribute the load?  Efficiency?  Those are good ideas but the way they are used is too ambiguous.
